# How to make sure no arguments are passed to a function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a function let's say ab() which does not take any arguments. How do I throw an error if one or more arguments are passed.

```
function ab(){
    a= 2;
    b=3;
    return a+b;

ab()
```

Now how do I throw error if ab('Hello')

I tried:

```js
function ab(){

    if(arguments.length>0) throw 'Cannot pass arguments to this function'
    a= 2;
    b=3;
    return a+b;
}
ab('Hello')
```

Not sure if arguments.length works this way, any other idea?

Comment: seems very odd. Did it work when you tried it with arguments?

Comment: It does in the snippet.

Comment: You're right, not sure why it does not work on my async function. I am not doing anything different there

Comment: Maybe there is a different definition for `arguments` there?

Comment: @swombhai may you update the question to include an async function example since that's what you're having issues with?

Comment: It works with async, but you'll need to `catch()` if you want to see the error.

Comment: Tried with try and catch, it worked, thanks all

Comment: This is why it's important to post a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JS `spread operator` (`...`) like so:

**although your version should work too**

**Also, as @Barmar said, *"This has the added benefit that it also works with arrow functions.***

```js
function my_function(...args) {
  if(args.length) throw "Args cannot be passed";
  console.log("No args are present");
}


my_function("Hello");
```

Comment: This has the added benefit that it also works with arrow functions.

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't think about that, good call, I'll feature your reply in my answer

Comment: Based on the comments, the problem isn't with detecting the arguments, it's with reporting the exception.